# pd.to_csv using different sep for rows

Tags: python, pandas, csv, txt

I read the following txt file with 'pd.read_csv(filename, sep = ',')'

read pass 1000K.
-128,-50,-48,-47,-41,-45,-41,-41,-39,-37
-127,-49,-46,-46,-40,-44,-40,-40,-38,-36
-126,-48,-44,-45,-39,-43,-39,-39,-37,-35
-125,-47,-42,-44,-38,-42,-38,-38,-36,-34

then I convert it to csv using
df = pd.to_csv(filename, index=None)
I get the following:

read pass 1000K.
-37
-36
-35
-34

only one column is preserved since it is default sep = ','
Anyone know how to keep the first row separated with ' ' and the other rows separated with ','?
so I can get all the data into cells

read|pass|1000K.
-128|-50|-48|-47|-41|-45|-41|-41|-39|-37
-127|-49|-46|-46|-40|-44|-40|-40|-38|-36
-126|-48|-44|-45|-39|-43|-39|-39|-37|-35
-125|-47|-42|-44|-38|-42|-38|-38|-36|-34

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following, and it is working fine.

hello.txt

```
read pass 1000K.
-128,-50,-48,-47,-41,-45,-41,-41,-39,-37
-127,-49,-46,-46,-40,-44,-40,-40,-38,-36
-126,-48,-44,-45,-39,-43,-39,-39,-37,-35
-125,-47,-42,-44,-38,-42,-38,-38,-36,-34
```

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.read_csv('hello.txt')

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
                                      read pass 1000K.
-128 -50 -48 -47 -41 -45 -41 -41 -39               -37
-127 -49 -46 -46 -40 -44 -40 -40 -38               -36
-126 -48 -44 -45 -39 -43 -39 -39 -37               -35
-125 -47 -42 -44 -38 -42 -38 -38 -36               -34


In [4]: df.to_csv("test3.csv")
```

Now If I check `test.csv` it has all columns preserved.

```
,,,,,,,,,read pass 1000K.
-128,-50,-48,-47,-41,-45,-41,-41,-39,-37
-127,-49,-46,-46,-40,-44,-40,-40,-38,-36
-126,-48,-44,-45,-39,-43,-39,-39,-37,-35
-125,-47,-42,-44,-38,-42,-38,-38,-36,-34
```

[image]

Comment: the issue is the the first row is 'read pass 1000K.' tho and I have to separate it using blanks.

Comment: Do you want to read the first row also, or can you skip it?

Comment: for some reason, I need to read and keep the first row as well.

Comment: Then it will save the first row in `,,,,,,,,,read pass 1000K.` this format because this is the default delimeter.

Comment: You also need to remove `index=None` as that is causing the error.